# Stack Overflow developer story positions

Tags: support, developer-story

Suppose I work as a consultant for Big Company A via TechRecruiter B.

Do I list Big Company A or TechRecruiter B or list both, and have one refer to the other (e.g. under TechRecruiter B, "Consultant for Big Company A" or under A, say "Consultant working through TechRecruiter B") and only fill out one section with all the skills/details?

Even more confusing is what happens when I have MyCompany LLC that did C2C work with TechRecruiter B and TechRecruiter C and TechRecruiter D for BigCompanyX, SmallCompanyY and MediumCompanyZ? Do I list it all under MyCompany LLC? Doing so would not show that I had worked for all these companies. But, if for example I worked for HAL via TechRecruiter via MyCompany LLC, and apply for HAL, they may think I was an employee rather than a consultant.

It is a bit confusing. I could use some guidance / advice as to the recommended approach here. Full-time, W2 employment is fairly straight-forward.

There also doesn't appear to be a way to list part-time vs full time. In some cases, the consulting work is 1-2 hours a month, but spans over the same time frame as full time employment. This could possibly make a potential hiring manager fear that I might take on a lot of side work, rather than just trying to help maintain existing clients on an as needed basis, as there does not seem to be a way to indicate that this is part time.

Is there a way to show location vs remote work or just type it in the description?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simplest to follow the conventional advice from [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/21967/2909).

> The ones for the consulting company are easy: you were their employee, so you can treat it as one job, and in the description you describe the most-significant assignments. You don't have to list all of them, just like you don't list every duty you performed for a regular job. In addition to being more compact, this is also clearer -- you don't represent yourself as having been employed by people who may not have chosen you (they just took the person your company sent).

In the context of a developer story, this may mean that you have the one job entry and you list the most prominent projects you worked on for each individual company.

If you *really* want to go a bit more granular, you can include that in your story as separate job listings, while making it explicit that you were a consultant for Big Company A.